# Client Cetificate IIS

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I have a dev server where I set up SSL and a client certificate using
[this guide form Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx)

My problem is I'm not sure what the steps are for getting a client certificate for my production server.  I was given a SSL cert from Entrust for my.url.com.

The "Enhanced Key Usage" says:

- Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
- Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)

I was wondering how do I use this for Client Authentication? I tried generating a cert with this certificate using makecert  but when I view the cert its says "This certificate does not appear to be valid for the selected purpose."  When I look at the cert chain the my.url.com cert is flagged with the same error.

Am I going about this the right way or am I missing something obvious?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure what the steps are for getting a client certificate for my production server.

To be clear a client certificate would be used to authenticate a user or a computer. Typically in an organization that needs to do this you establish a PKI server. In a Windows environment you do this by installing Active Directory Certificate Services https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/dd448615.aspx. So if you went to a website and you had to login to that website, you could use a client certificate instead of a username and password to login to the website if the website is designed to allow that. For client certificates the user needs to install their certificate in the browser they are going to use to login to the website. Client certificates are created by Active Directory Certificate Services.

If you are looking for a certificate to enable SSL on your website you need a certificate that can be used for Web Authentication. If you are using web authentication certificate you need to follow the specific directions for installing an SSL certificate with your web server.

If you are looking for a certificate to enable terminal services (Remote Desktop Services) you want a certificate that can be used for Server Authentication. If you want to install a server authentication certificate for remote desktop services you would create the certificate using Active Directory Certificate Services and then install it on the server.